# Android app for backing up SMS messages from SIM card

Tags: gratis, android, backup

Does anyone know of a (preferably gratis) app for Android that can read SMS messages stored on a SIM card, and output them to as a file (XML, CSV, some neutral format) onto internal storage or SD card.

Note that this answer is not suitable:
[Backup and view text messages from Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19167/backup-and-view-text-messages-from-android). *SMS To Text* only works if the messages are stored on the phone itself.

I am running Android 2.1, and the built-in Messaging app doesn't allow me to copy SMS messages from the SIM card to the phone (the only option present when viewing old messages is 'delete').*

<sup>*I understand that if I long-press a message on the 'Manage SIM card messages' screen I can copy it to the phone memory, but some information such as sender and date would be lost. This is unfortunate, and impractical for 100+ messages.</sup>

Comment: It has been ages since I've last used SMS on SIM card (and I doubt many people still do), so I cannot tell which app will give success here. But you can check with my list of apps to [Backup SMS/MMS](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup#group_133) to narrow down your search.